# Changing root mysql password failed when done from mysql CLI

Tags: command-line, mysql

Consider the following code:

```
UPDATE user set password=PASSWORD('NEWPASSWORD_CAME_HERE') WHERE User='root';
```

Where it is written `NEWPASSWORD_CAME_HERE` I've putted my password (between the quote marks).

Yet when I executed this query I got this error:

> ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

Why have I got this error?, I followed different guides and this is the most traditional way I've seen so I can't understand why it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you'd have to specify the database in your UPDATE statement, not only the table:

```
UPDATE mysql.user ...
```

otherwise MySQL can't know on which database you're operating (hence the error).

However, this is not the proper way to change an user's password in MySQL. Fiddling with the `mysql` database (which contains database metadata) is not recommended. Do this instead:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('NEWPASSWORD_CAME_HERE');
```

Answer (score -2):

to solve your error:
`use mysql`

But you should have a look at mysql reference manual:

```
ALTER USER user IDENTIFIED BY 'auth_string';
```

[SET PASSWORD Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html)